# How to use wildcard in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, linker, wildcard

The following snippet:

```
... rest of makefile ...
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usb_bsp.c
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usb_core.c
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usb_dcd.c
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usbd_cdc_core.c 
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usbd_cdc_vcp.c 
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usb_dcd_int.c 
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usbd_core.c 
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usbd_desc.c 
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usbd_ioreq.c 
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usbd_req.c 
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/usbd_usr.c
... rest of makefile
```

Compiles, but if I replace it by:

```
SRCS += $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/$(wildcard *.c)
```

`make` command returns a linker error:

```
FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/User.o: No such file or directory
```

The `STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB` directory contains no other `.c` files than the ones listed in the first code snippet. **Am I using the wildcard incorrectly here?**

Comment: It seems that you need to include the object file.  You may consult the [make man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html).

Comment: wildcard looks where you told it. You told it to: (1) look for all files called *.c and (2) put `$(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/` in front of that text

Comment: suggest: `SRCS := $(wildcard $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/*.c)`  then you can obtain the object and dependency names via: `OBJ := $(SRCS:.c=.o)` and `DEP := $(SRCS:.c=.d)`

Comment: Here's a tip: run `ls <wildcard-expression>` at the shell prompt.  If that returns what you want, then in your makefile write `$(wildcard <wildcard-expression>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SRCS += $(wildcard $(BASEDIR)FingerCell/Source/STM32F4-DISCOVERY_USB/*.c)
```